# bash not running npm or npx commands

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm

I am currently trying to programmatically run a `npx eleventy` function through a bash  script (on a cronjob)

I have tried it on my terminal, it works perfectly fine, ran a command as such

```
cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npx eleventy
```

Also did checked the following

`npm -v` - `6.14.5`
and

`npx -v` - `6.14.5`

running `which npm` returns `/usr/local/bin/npm` and
running `which npx` returns `/usr/local/bin/npx`

However, running the following commands (below) in the bash script doesn't work...

**test.bash**

```
cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npx eleventy
cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npx -v
cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npm -v
```

throwing the following error: `env: node: No such file or directory`.

However, it seems that I do have node on running the following command,

```
cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/node -v
```

returns `v12.16.1`

Seek some help please!

Edit:

my cronjob

```
* * * * * bash /Users/me/Desktop/test.bash >> /Users/me/Desktop/testvimbackup.log 2>&1
```

Output of `echo PATH=$PATH 1>&2`:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

Comment: Add your cronjob to your question (no comment).

Comment: Added my cronjob in!

Comment: Since the message says '**env**: node: No such file or directory', I would conclude, that the error comes from an execution of a `#!/usr/local/bin/env node`, which in turn means, that your PATH is not set up correctly in your cron job. Do a `echo PATH=$PATH 1>&2` in your `test.bash` and check the output of the next cron execution.

Comment: Done that, output is the following `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is because `crontab` run with an empty environment.

try sourcing your profile like this (in the script)

```
. $HOME/.bash_profile

cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npx eleventy
cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npx -v
cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npm -v
```

(or try with `. $HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc` if it didn't work)

**Alternative:** setting the path to node manually

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin


cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npx eleventy

cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npx -v

cd /Users/me/Desktop/test-folder/public && /usr/local/bin/npm -v
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. `. $HOME/.bash_profile` ran but pointed my PATH in another direction to `PATH=/Users/me/miniconda3/bin:/Users/me/miniconda3/condabin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

Comment: do replace `. $HOME/.bash_profile` with `. $HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc` and see if works

Comment: Tried with both of those too, but they both threw the same message `/Users/me/.bashrc: No such file or directory`

Comment: mhm. where is `node` located? `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: yep, `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: oh, alright I think you can just replace the `. $HOME/.bash_profile` line with `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` then

Comment: oh great! that worked perfectly! do you think you could explain what was going on?